# Rotation operator in the matrix representation in the standard basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, rotation

I recently been introduced to rotation operators in Quantum-Mechanics.

Can someone please provide an explanation on what is means to represent a operator for the rotation of a quantum-mechanical system around the z-axis in the matrix representation in the standard basis.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'the standard basis'?

Comment: @jacob1729 That is part of the reason this question is causing me issues. I'm not sure what this means. If I take the angular momentum $l=1$ and make the angle of rotation $\phi = \frac {\pi} 4$. Does this help?

Comment: Still haven’t had much progress on this question. I don’t think it would be like a standard rotation matrix as that acts on a Euclidean Space and this question relates to Hilbert Spaces.

Comment: Do you know what a representation is (in the sense of group theory)? Do you understand the idea that rotation operators can be obtained by exponentiating angular momentum operators?

Comment: I understand the concept that a generalization for an arbitrary rotation would be given as follows: $\hat R_u(\alpha)= e^{\frac {-i} {h}\alpha u \hat L}$, where $\alpha$ is the angle of rotation and $\hat L$ is the angular momentum operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm confused by the phrase 'standard basis' and think that is non-standard terminology. However, there's only one thing I think it could be.)

From the general theory of angular momentum we know that a spin $j$ object has a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ of dimension $2j+1$. This Hilbert space is spanned by kets $|j,m\rangle$ where $-j \leq m \leq +j$ and the $m$'s differ by integers. The $m$'s correspond to the eigenvalues of the operator $J_z$ whilst the $j$'s are the related to the total angular momentum $J^2$. For this discussion, the $j$'s simply label which representation (Hilbert space) you are working in.

Take for example, $l=1$. Then $L_z$ is an operator whose eigenkets are precisely the $|1,m\rangle$s with eigenvalues $m$. That is, $L_z$ is diagonal in this basis with matrix representation:

$$ L_z = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$

It is important to note that the meaning of this matrix is the representation of an infinitesimal rotation. More precisely, for a finite rotation $\theta$ we can break it up into $N$ infinitesimal rotations $\theta/N$. This rotation then has representation:

$$U(\theta/N) = I - i\theta L_z/N$$

Multiplying all of these out and using the identity $\lim_{N\to\infty} (1+x/N)^N=\exp(x)$ gives:

$$U(\theta) = \exp(-i \theta L_z)$$

Exponentiating a diagonal matrix is easy:

$$U(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}e^{-i\theta} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & e^{i\theta} \end{pmatrix} $$

Notice that this is not the usual rotation in matrix in $R^3$. However, it is related to it by a change of basis, just one that uses complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jacob.